# Approaches to persist enum in java

Tags: java, jpa, enums

Good afternoon everyone,

I'm doing an api to order participants in different competitions. The competitions have different trials, for example, push-ups and run. The point is that trials can be measured in different ways, in this case, push-ups in reps and run in seconds, so I guess the best way of doing this is having a method that can be override, lets say `getRating(int mark)`, where `mark` would be 5 push ups or 10 seconds. That method will return the rating the athlete will have in that trial.

From my point of view, I have two approaches. The first one is using an enum, but since I want to persist the info, I'm not quite sure about how to do it. I've seen that i need to use the `@Enumerated` notation [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-persisting-enums-in-jpa). This I think will solve the problem but if I want to get information about the trials after (name, description or any other attribute I include), will I have problems since they are not in the DB? Also it is important to notice that if there is only one competition this won't be really a problem, but if the number starts to grow, the number of trials will increase even more, so I don't really know if this is the best approach.

This would be something similar to this:

```
public enum Trial {
    PUSH_UPS("Push-ups", "Test your upper body strength by doing push-ups.") {
        @Override
        public String getRating(int result) {
            if (result >= 40) {
                return "Excellent";
            } else if (result >= 30) {
                return "Good";
            } else if (result >= 20) {
                return "Fair";
            } else {
                return "Poor";
            }
        }
    },
    PULL_UPS("Pull-ups", "Test your upper body strength by doing pull-ups.") {
        @Override
        public String getRating(int result) {
            if (result >= 20) {
                return "Excellent";
            } else if (result >= 15) {
                return "Good";
            } else if (result >= 10) {
                return "Fair";
            } else {
                return "Poor";
            }
        }
    },
    RUNNING("Running", "Test your cardiovascular endurance by running.") {
        @Override
        public String getRating(int result) {
            if (result <= 420) { // 7 minutes (420 seconds) for 1 mile
                return "Excellent";
            } else if (result <= 540) { // 9 minutes (540 seconds) for 1 mile
                return "Good";
            } else if (result <= 660) { // 11 minutes (660 seconds) for 1 mile
                return "Fair";
            } else {
                return "Poor";
            }
        }
    };

    private final String name;
    private final String description;

    Trial(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public abstract String getRating(int result);
}
```

The second one is having an abstract class and extends from it every single trial. In order to persist I think a single table would be the best choice. From here I have a question, with this approach do I need a single Service, a single DAO and a single Controller for every trial? Is there a way to simplify this structure?

This would be the abstract class

```
public abstract class Trial {
    private final String name;
    private final String description;

    protected Trial(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public abstract String getRating(int result);
}
```

This would be the trials:

```
public class PushUpsTrial extends Trial {
    public PushUpsTrial() {
        super("Push-ups", "Test your upper body strength by doing push-ups.");
    }

    @Override
    public String getRating(int result) {
        if (result >= 40) {
            return "Excellent";
        } else if (result >= 30) {
            return "Good";
        } else if (result >= 20) {
            return "Fair";
        } else {
            return "Poor";
        }
    }
}

public class PullUpsTrial extends Trial {
    public PullUpsTrial() {
        super("Pull-ups", "Test your upper body strength by doing pull-ups.");
    }

    @Override
    public String getRating(int result) {
        if (result >= 20) {
            return "Excellent";
        } else if (result >= 15) {
            return "Good";
        } else if (result >= 10) {
            return "Fair";
        } else {
            return "Poor";
        }
    }
}

public class RunningTrial extends Trial {
    public RunningTrial() {
        super("Running", "Test your cardiovascular endurance by running.");
    }

    @Override
    public String getRating(int result) {
        if (result <= 420) { // 7 minutes (420 seconds) for 1 mile
            return "Excellent";
        } else if (result <= 540) { // 9 minutes (540 seconds) for 1 mile
            return "Good";
        } else if (result <= 660) { // 11 minutes (660 seconds) for 1 mile
            return "Fair";
        } else {
            return "Poor";
        }
    }
}
```

So the question I'm asking is, which approach is better? Is there another better way of solving this problem? Is the solution the same in the end?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.